# Do Swift-based applications work on OS version 10.13.6 (High Sierra) with xcode version 9.4.1 because of my iMAC (mid2011) Apple not provide Update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

[image]

4
I have a Mac early 2011 running MacOS high sierra 10.13.6. My Mac can't upgrade to higher MacOS versions.

I need to install XCode 11 to take advantage of SwiftUI.

Comment: You seem aware that your machine won't let you use the right version of Xcode so that you can use SwiftUI.  So what's your question?

Comment: Apple's answer, roughly speaking, is: "pound sand." Buy a new mac, throw out the old, and be a good little consumer

Answer (score 0):

With macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) you can run Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61). Xcode 10.1 includes Swift 4.2.1 and SDKs for iOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1, tvOS 12.1, and macOS Mojave.

So you can make and run Swift 4.2.1 based applications for macOS and iOS 12 but you can't use Swift 5.x or SwiftUI which started with Xcode 10.2 and Xcode 11.

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/whats-new/

You can download Xcode from Apple but there is a handy list here: https://xcodereleases.com